# Find $P(A∩B)$ and $P(A'∪B')$

Tags: probability

For my IB Math class, I have a test on probability and statistics next week. I'm reviewing practice problems in the book and working on some to prepare myself for the test. This is a problem I'm having a little trouble with:

> For the events $A$ and $B$, $P(A) = 0.6$, $P(B) = 0.8$ and $P(A\cup B)=1$. 
>   Find $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A'\cap B')$.

For $P(A\cap B)$, can I use this: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A\cup B)$?

And for $P(A'\cup B')$, do I do $1-P(A) + 1-P(B)$?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, for $P(A\cap B)$.  For the second question, $P(A'\cup B') = P((A\cap B)') = 1- P(A\cap B)$

Comment: @amWhy Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $P(A\cap B) = P(A)+P(B) - P(A\cup B)$.  In this case, that means $$P(A\cap B) = 0.6+0.8 - 1.0 = 0.4$$

In determining the second question, we will find the and answer in the first question very useful in the second case, because the second case is essentially the probability of the complement of the first outcome.

For determining $P(A'\cup B')$, we use DeMorgan's Rule for sets which tells us $A'\cup B' = (A\cap B)'$.  So we are needing to find $P((A\cap B)')$ which is equal to $$P(A'\cup B') = P((A\cap B)') = 1-P(A\cap B) = 1- 0.4= 0.6$$